# Add columns from a different source in each row on an SSIS ETL

Tags: ssis, etl

I'm trying to do a data migration, in which the two tables that I'm migrating are different, they have the data that I need, but the columns and formats are different. My workflow currently looks like this:

[image: My SSIS table migration workflow]

As you can see I'm migrating from MSC_CTAA_SUCURSAL_DEPENDENCIA to a flat file, but I have another source which is COMMONS_DEF_CATALOGOS, which brings some foreign keys that I need to append to each row. These sources are in completely different databases.

The problem that I'm having is that as you can see I'm migrating 4 rows from MSC and I'm grabbing 1 row that holds two colums from COMMONS, I want to append the two columns from COMMONS to each row that comes from MSC, I have tried UNION ALL, MERGE, but it only adds the info from COMMONS as a new row, which you can see in the final output which are 5 rows.

What can I do to add the data from COMMONS into each row and not add a new row?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to join the information to add a new column.

If you don't have key column, you can use the "merge" component.

If you have a key, you can use "Merge Join" but you have to  sort the data on the key column firstly.

[image]

Comment: I was overcomplicating it myself, I just use a constant in a Derived Column that was the value that I used in the WHERE clause in the COMMONS data source. By using the lookup it was putting the values on every row.